# cordova-plugin-geolocation watchPosition() method not working

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm working on a Ionic2-Angular2-Typescript application. I'm trying to use Cordova's Geolocation plugin, but when I call watchPosition method like in http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/ editor shows me some errors:

> Error TS2339: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Geoposition | PositionError'.
>
> Error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type 'Geoposition | PositionError'.

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Geolocation, PositionError, Geoposition } from 'ionic-native';

export class LocationProvider {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    var subscription = Geolocation.watchPosition()
                          .filter((p) => p.code === undefined) //Filter Out Errors
                          .subscribe(position => {
  console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem as follows:

```
this.subscription = Geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(position => {
    if ((position as Geoposition).coords != undefined) {
      var geoposition = (position as Geoposition);
      console.log('Latitude: ' + geoposition.coords.latitude + ' - Longitude: ' + geoposition.coords.longitude);
    } else { 
      var positionError = (position as PositionError);
      console.log('Error ' + positionError.code + ': ' + positionError.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting a type inside the callback functions? Makes for a shorter code if you're not interested in the errors anyway.

Something like this (not tested):

```
this.subscription = Geolocation.watchPosition()
    .filter((p: any) => p['code'] === undefined) // Filter Out Errors
    .subscribe((position: GeoPosition) => {
        console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
    });
```

Comment: I don't know why but this does not work. I finally solved my problem as I posted in an answer here. Checking if position is Geoposition or PositionError type.