# How to return back the data value from service providers to components | Angular 4 | Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to return back the geolocation latitude, and longitude value from my service provider file.

Code shown below. 
component or pages 'home.ts'

```
import { WeatherProvider } from '../../providers/weather/weather';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private weatherProvider: WeatherProvider) {
    console.log(this.weatherProvider.getGeoLocation()+'kkk');
  }
```

provider file 'weather.ts'

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
....
....
constructor(public http: Http, private geolocation: Geolocation) { }
getGeoLocation() {
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  // console.log(resp.coords.latitude)
  //  console.log(resp.coords.longitude)
    return resp;

   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });

  }
```

I'am getting result as undefined. I'am newbie in typescript, sorry for the silly question. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise from your service and chain in your component.

```
getGeoLocation() {
   //return the promise
   return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  // console.log(resp.coords.latitude)
  //  console.log(resp.coords.longitude)
    return resp;

   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });

  }
```

In your component, call `Promise.then()` to access the `resp` returned from the promise,

```
this.weatherProvider.getGeoLocation()
    then(loc => {
        console.log(loc);
     });
```

Comment: One doubt why we want to promise. How its working in typescript

Comment: TypeScript is a transpile for JavaScript, and JavaScript is assincronous.

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are javascript feature.. It allows you to handle async operations @Rijo.

Comment: I'm getting result as [object Promise], how to split and take the values

Comment: Check the second part of the answer.. you will get value within `then`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: I add like this                this.weatherProvider.getGeoLocation().then(loc => {
      console.log(loc.coords.latitude);    });    
     but coords getting error

Comment: that may be something else unrelated to your question.. what is the error?

Comment: console.log(loc.coords.latitude); I'am getting result as success. But editor showing error as [ts]
Property 'coords' does not exist on type 'void | Geoposition'.
  Property 'coords' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: that is a different issue I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698851/cordova-plugin-geolocation-watchposition-method-not-working will solve that error. You may need to debug your code further

Answer (score 0):

You should add return before call this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition because it is a promise.

```
constructor(public http: Http, private geolocation: Geolocation) { }
getGeoLocation() {
   return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
   // console.log(resp.coords.latitude)
   //  console.log(resp.coords.longitude)
       return resp;

   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code your service 'weather.ts'**

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
....
....
constructor(public http: Http, private geolocation: Geolocation) { }
getGeoLocation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then((resp) => {
           resolve(resp.json());
      }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting location', error);
            reject(error);
      });
});

  }
```

**And your component file:**

```
import { WeatherProvider } from '../../providers/weather/weather';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private weatherProvider: WeatherProvider){
    this.weatherProvider.getGeoLocation()
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
         })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
      });
  }
```